# Is it possible to do this in golang?

Tags: go, yaml

I have a doubt about the `.yaml` files in golang, suppose I have a `.yaml` file with the following content:

```
print:
  1

print:
  2

print:
  3
```

Is there a way to get all the `print` in the yaml file? How would I represent that structure in golang? Because for example if I have this in a `.yaml` file:

```
print:
  1
```

In golang I can represent it like this:

```
type Print struct {
  Print int `yaml:"print"`
}
```

And if that cannot be done, what other way would there be to do something similar? Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate keys are not allowed in yaml

Comment: @BurakSerdar Oh, so is there a way to do something similar?

Answer (score 6):

Your YAML is not legal. You can't have the same key multiples times in a mapping. From [3.2.1.1 of the spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#3211-nodes)...

> The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key/value node pairs, with the restriction that ***each of the keys is unique***.

Instead, use a [mapping to a sequence](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#21-collections).

```
print: [1,2,3]
```

And store it as an `[]int`.

```
type Print struct {
  Print []int `yaml:"print"`
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried with a list and it worked